# How do I solve $z' = 10^{x+z}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $z' = 10^{x+z}$?

I tried first by saying $z' = 10^x10^z$

After solving the integrals seperatly I got to $-10^{-z} = 10^x \rightarrow z=x + c$

Btw, the integrals are $\int \frac{1}{10^z}dz = \int 10^xdx$

But in the answers it is $z = -log(c-10^x)$

Comment: this is separable: $z' 10^{-z} = 10^x$. Just integrate both sides

Comment: @User8128 I did

Comment: $10=e^a$ for some value of a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\int a^x \,\mbox{d}x = \frac{a^x}{\ln a} + C$$
but you can get rid of these denominators by multiplying both sides afterwards. So you got to:

> After solving the integrals seperatly I got to $-10^{-z} = 10^x$

Don't forget the constant of integration in this step. Then proceed carefully:
$$-10^{-z} = 10^x + C \iff 10^{-z} = -10^x-C \iff -z = \log\left( -10^x-C \right)$$

You can finish from here? Rename $c=-C$ to fit with the given answer.

Answer (score 2):

By rearranging, we have

$$z'10^{-z}=10^x$$

$$\int z'10^{-z}dx=\int10^xdx$$

$u=z,du=z'dx$

$$\int10^{-u}du=\frac1{\ln(10)}10^x+C_1$$

$$\frac{-1}{\ln(10)}10^{-u}=\frac1{\ln(10)}10^x+C_1$$

$C_2=\ln(10)C_1$

$$-10^{-z}=10^x+C_2$$

$$z=-\log_{10}(-10^x-C_2)$$

Then $c=-C_2$ to get

$$z=-\log_{10}(c-10^x)$$